# Problema al imprimir datos

Tags: php, html, sql, bootstrap

quiero imprimir textos en modo alertas bootstrap, pero me sale el error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Proyectos\ProyectoDriversParadeClub\DriversParadeClub\view\reportes_de_usuarios.view.php
>   on line 121 Array

He hecho un var_dump y la consulta la hace correcta, es a la hora de imprimirlo, os paso el código:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
                <?php
                include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';
                $sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM reporteusu WHERE id';

                $gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
                $gsnet->execute();

                $resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();

                echo $resultado; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Creo que tu problema es en el query, ve que al final pones WHERE id, pero no especificas el valor de 'id'

Answer (score 0):

inentena asi, ademas de pasarle el valor del Id que deseas.

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <?php
        include_once '../pruebas/conexion.php';
        $sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM reporteusu WHERE id= 1';

        $gsnet = $pdo->prepare($sql_leer);
        $gsnet->execute();

        $resultado = $gsnet->fetchAll();
        for ($j=0; $j< $resultado.length ; $j++) {
            echo $resultado[$j]."<br>";
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

espero te sirva bro... ReNiceCode...

Comment: Cambie el fetchAll por  fetchColumn y me funcionó, gracias de todas formas!

Comment: bueno, bro... me aegro que te haya solucionado

Answer (score 0):

no puedes decirle echo $resultado porque cuando le dices que te traiga los datos de la consulta con un fetchAll te los trae en un arreglo en ves de

```
echo $resultado;
```

pon

```
print_r($resultado);
```

Comment: Entonces por que en vez de FetchAll, no pusiste fetchColumn para que no me printase un arreglo? Un print_r no es lo correcto para meter en una alerta de bootstrap.

Comment: tienes razón, aunque aun poniendo el fetchAll también podría  hacer un simple foreach para ir mostrando los datos

Answer (score 0):

tienes un **error**  en esta linea

```
$sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM reporteusu WHERE id';
```

tienes que espesificar que el id sea igual a x nuemro o x string por ejemplo

```
 $sql_leer = 'SELECT * FROM reporteusu WHERE id=5';
```

son los pequeños errores que aveces nos vuelven locos por andar de rapidos jeje

Comment: aunque es cierto ese punto, el error esta en tratar de imprimir con la sentencia echo un array de datos por eso el mensaje de error

Comment: tambien , buen punto amigo